# short_code is missing (for a region in US territory) in mapbox geocoding API response

Tags: mapbox, geocoding

short_code is required for us to translate a region/location name to zip codes. We are able to get the short_code for denver region using mapbox geocoding API. However, short_code for Cayey(region in Puerto Rico territory) is **missing** in the same API response. Please see more details in the contract below.

Another observation is that the country for Cayey is shown as Puerto Rico instead of US.

[https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/denver.json?access_token={{token}}&autocomplete=true&country=US&types=region,district,place,locality&limit=20](https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/denver.json?access_token=%7B%7Btoken%7D%7D&autocomplete=true&country=US&types=region,district,place,locality&limit=20)

Mapbox geocodong response for 'denver':

```
{
  "context": [
    {
      "id": "region.10002699958017490",
      "wikidata": "Q1261",
      "short_code": "US-CO",
      "text": "Colorado"
    },
    {
      "id": "country.19678805456372290",
      "wikidata": "Q30",
      "short_code": "us",
      "text": "United States"
    }
  ]
}
```

[https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/cayey.json?access_token={{token}}&autocomplete=true&country=US&types=region,district,place,locality&limit=20](https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/cayey.json?access_token=%7B%7Btoken%7D%7D&autocomplete=true&country=US&types=region,district,place,locality&limit=20)

Mapbox geocoding response for 'Cayey':

```
    {
      "context": [
        {
          "id": "region.11316909078893780",
          "wikidata": "Q2307508",
          "text": "Cayey"
        },
        {
          "id": "country.16776721557498950",
          "wikidata": "Q1183",
          "short_code": "pr",
          "text": "Puerto Rico"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Could mapbox team help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoshikage Ochi's answer is correct: short_code is an optional property that is not always included in the [Mapbox Geocoding API response object](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding-response-object).

Specific to your Puerto Rico example: There are a handful of areas that don’t play by the “rules” in ISO 3166-1. They are considered [countries and/or subdivisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2#Subdivisions_included_in_ISO_3166-1). Puerto Rico is one of those areas, which don't have ISO 3166-2 specified regions/provinces. As there is no ISO 3166-2 code for features within Puerto Rico, it isn't possible to include a short_code for the feature `Cayey` in the Mapbox Geocoding API response.

In the ISO standard, Puerto Rico is treated as a country, since it has an [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes) assigned code "pr". As it is treated as a country, "short_code": "us" would not be in the country context.

Answer (score 2):

As the [document](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding-response-object) explains, `short_code` is optional. Therefore, it's not guaranteed it's always included.